# What is the custom dns target generated in Heroku for?

Tags: heroku

I have just deployed a new application in Heroku and was configuring a custom domain for the same by adding the following CNAME record:

```
CNAME        abc        someapp.herokuapp.com        Auto
```

And then in the Heroku CLI, I ran the following command:

```
heroku domains:add --app someapp abc.example.com
```

---

Now If I go to `abc.example.com`, it takes me to the application as I wanted but what I'm confused about is the output below that I get when running the `heroku domains:add` command above:

```
Configure your app's DNS provider to point to the DNS Target random-words-dfgkonqyuiu37shnb6.herokudns.com.
```

---

What exactly is this generated DNS target `random-words-dfgkonqyuiu37shnb6.herokudns.com` for when the DNS target that I added earlier seems to be working fine?

Answer (score 2):

random-words-dfgkonqyuiu37shnb6.herokudns.com is the random DNS target assigned by Heroku. Heroku randomly assigns DNS targets any time you add a custom domain name.

To properly point your custom domain name towards your Heroku app you should modify the CNAME record at your domain provider as follows:

```
CNAME        abc        random-words-dfgkonqyuiu37shnb6.herokudns.com
```

I bought a custom domain at GoDaddy and am currently trying to work through pointing it towards my Heroku app built with Node.js, express, and using a MongoDB. I don't know where you bought your custom domain name. But, GoDaddy doesn't play so well with Heroku.